# Android - Adjusting Image View Position on Top of a Zoomable Image View

Tags: java, android, image, math, pinchzoom

I'm working on image, making a feature which allows user to **place tags on images** (like Facebook photo tag). I have a zoomable ImageView (using [Mike Ortiz's TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)) as a background image, and some ImageViews as image tags.

Each tag has **X** and **Y** position, and there is no problem in displaying both background image and image tags in correct position. However, when user triggers pinch zoom, the position of background image is changed. Which means, the position of each image tags must also be changed/updated according to the current background image's **zoom level** and **scroll position**.

I'm currently using this method:

```
float currentZoom = mImageView.getCurrentZoom();
float zoomedX = x / currentZoom;
float zoomedY = y / currentZoom;
```

But when I tried, it went totally wrong. Can anyone help me finding correct method/equation?

**EDIT:**

I tried using **Matrix.mapPoints()**, but I don't understand how this matrix could help me solving my problem. Here is an image for better explanation:

[image]

Comment: use Matrix.mapPoints()

Comment: I tried it before. It gave me 3x3 matrix, stored in a float[]. I could get image coordinate as well as its zoom level from there. But that does not solve my problem. How do I find the coordinate of image tag after the image is zoomed & scrolled?

Comment: as i said use Matrix.mapPoints() use two float points so the input array has length of 2

Comment: try Matrix m = tiv.getImageMatrix(); float[] pts = {0, 0}; m.mapPoints(pts); and see whats in 'pts'

Comment: I put your code inside the "zoom listener" in my code. When I do the zoom (the zoom scale was **1.0941195**), the `float[] pts` gives me `[0] = -33.788258` and `[1] = 4.5877075`. Can you explain these values?

Comment: the pixel [0, 0] of your image is "drawn" at location [-33.788258, 4.5877075]

Comment: I've tried your method. It works perfectly for image scrolling! But now the last problem is how to get image tag's **X** & **Y** position after zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally get the answer (thanks to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink))! To get the exact tag position on image, all we have to do is to use **Matrix.mapPoints()**. But that alone will not give the new **X** & **Y** position after zoom. We have to multiply the current **X** & **Y** position with the **current zoom level** to get the "**after zoom position**".

In other words:

```
Matrix matrix = mImageView.getImageMatrix();
float[] pts = {0, 0};
matrix.mapPoints(pts);
float newTagX = (tagX * currentZoom) + pts[0];
float newTagY = (tagY * currentZoom) + pts[1];
```

Comment: no, no, no: `float[] pts = {0, 0}` was just for testing you need to use tag's coords `float[] pts = {tagX, tagY}`

Comment: If I use that method, image tags are perfectly confined to a coordinate on the background image. Which means, no matter how much I scroll the image, image tags are staying still in their current position (which is not what I wanted). I want it so when I scroll the image, the tag positions are being updated according to the current scroll position. So I need to use a fixed (0, 0) coordinate. But thanks anyway!